# Facebook send app in review, how i can generate a free privacy policy?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, privacy

I'm trying to send in review to facebook my facebook-app (related to an ios app) that post on users walls, photos and text (i'm using publish_action). Facebook require my a privacy url:

```
"privacy policy for login dialog and app details"
```

How i can create a privacy policy for my facebook app? I'm not a lawyer and my ios app doesn't require registration so i haven't a privacy and terms... I have found only a privacy generator focused on "facebook app" it is Iubenta but it's free only for the first privacy generation... The other generators aren't focused on "facebook app login dialog and app details", there a free solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also had this problem and i searched for solutions. You can do this:

[Copy from this site the privacy policy](http://www.inforbiro.com/blog-eng/facebook-app-privacy-policy-example/) from "Application Privacy Statement" to bottom and replace [COMPANY-NAME] With your company name and [COMPANY-EMAIL] with company email and after that I've created a Wordpress free blog/site and posted it there.

I used it for Facebook like button submission and it worked for me. Hope it helps you too.

This is how my privacy policy looks like [click here to see](https://appstarry.wordpress.com/2015/02/07/facebook-privacy-policy/)

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly the same as in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29938358/12066144) of Silviu St but I put the text in a markdown file on my GitHub repo instead:

- I copied the text from [this website](https://www.inforbiro.com/blog/facebook-app-privacy-policy-example).
- I changed `[COMPANY-NAME]` to mine and changed the date at the end.
- Then I put the text in a `.md` file on my GitHub repo (instead of using wordpress) and it worked